# width of my root div is not showing 100% in mobile dimension

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I created a simple react.js . it set very thing so simple. i create folder by npx create-react-app .

I also set * { margin: 0;padding: 0; box-sizzing: border-box}.

I set body background-color: red; and #root background-color: #fff; to show you clear.

It is totally fine in desktop dimension. but It is so ugly in mobile dimension. the whole #root div component get compared.

[desktop view shows no irregularity]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFD0p.jpg

**[error in mobile dimension]**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOmo.png

[some of code Screen Short][]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISUZa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/89CeQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `#root {width: 100%}`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.